# ListView expand animation for items only works after second click

Tags: android, onclick, android-animation, android-view, visibility

I have a CardView with the following views:

```
- RelativeLayout (view_1)
    - TextView
    - TextView

- RelativeLayout (view_2)
    - ImageView
    - ImageView
```

When i open my `ListView` view_2 is set to `Visible.GONE` so you cant see it. 
Now i used the `ExpandAnimation` from [this blog](http://blog.udinic.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/). Here you have the code:

```
/**
 *
 */
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    /**
     *
     */
    private AnimationCallback callback = null;
    /**
     *
     */
    private View viewToAnimate = null;
    /**
     *
     */
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewToAnimateLayoutParams = null;
    /**
     *
     */
    private int marginStart = 0;
    /**
     *
     */
    private int marginEnd = 0;
    /**
     *
     */
    private boolean isVisibleAfter = false;
    /**
     *
     */
    private boolean isEndedAlready = false;

    /**
     *
     * @param callback
     * @param view
     * @param duration
     */
    public ExpandAnimation(AnimationCallback callback, View view, int duration) {
        this.setDuration(duration);

        this.callback = callback;

        this.viewToAnimate = view;
        this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        this.isVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

        this.marginStart = this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        this.marginEnd = (this.marginStart == 0 ? (0 - view.getHeight()) : 0);

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param interpolatedTime
     * @param transformation
     */
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, transformation);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin = this.marginStart + (int) ((this.marginEnd - this.marginStart) * interpolatedTime);
            this.viewToAnimate.requestLayout();
        } else if (!this.isEndedAlready) {
            this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin = this.marginEnd;
            this.viewToAnimate.requestLayout();

            if (this.isVisibleAfter) {
                this.viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            this.isEndedAlready = true;

            this.callback.onAnimationCompleted(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I use it inside my `AdapterView`:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, AnimationCallback {
    private TextView textViewValue = null;
    private TextView textViewTime = null;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutExpand = null;
    private ImageView imageViewMood = null;
    private ImageView imageViewMeal = null;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.textViewValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_value);
        this.textViewTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_time);
        this.relativeLayoutExpand = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_expand);
        this.imageViewMood = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_mood);
        this.imageViewMeal = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_meal);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.animate(this.relativeLayoutExpand);
    }

    public void animate(final View view) {
        ExpandAnimation expand = new ExpandAnimation(this, view, 500);

        view.startAnimation(expand);
    }

    public void onAnimationCompleted(int position) {
    }
}
```

I only have one problem now: When i expand an item inside my list the first time it appears instantly without animation and after it the closing and opening works smoothly with animation.

Does someone know why the first opening happens without animation but every click after that is triggering the correct animation?

I also need the animation for the first click.

**EDIT**

Is it because initially my views visibility is `GONE` and so the height is unknown? If yes: How could i solve this?

**EDIT 2**

No, my XML layout file does not set the view to `GONE`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_textview_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/text_value"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_textview_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_textview_value"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_imageview_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/text_description"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_expand"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_data"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_mood"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/text_mood"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolorsecundary"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_imageview_mood"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/text_description"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_imageview_meal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_mood"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/text_description" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I set the `View.GONE` in my ListAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...

    viewHolder.textViewTime.setText(time);
    viewHolder.textViewValue.setText(value + " " + unitValue);
    viewHolder.relativeLayoutExpand.setVisibility(View.GONE); // <-- HERE

    ...
}
```

**Edit 3**

Maybe it is important to know that the container of my cardviews is a recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_textview_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_textview_name">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_parent"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:layout_behavior="de.hof.ime_dc.idia_move.views.buttons.ScrollFABBehaviour"
            app:rippleColor="@color/accentColor" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I really need a solution for that. It is disturbing many of needed functionality.

**Edit 4**

I added some Log-Outputs:

```
=============================== EXPAND =========================================

08-02 12:27:22.471   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 8 (GONE)
08-02 12:27:22.471   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginStart: 0
08-02 12:27:22.471   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginEnd: 0
08-02 12:27:22.472   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 0 (VISIBLE)

============================== COLLAPSE ========================================

08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 0 (VISIBLE)
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginStart: 0
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginEnd: -156
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 8 (GONE)

=============================== EXPAND =========================================

08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 8 (GONE)
08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginStart: -156
08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginEnd: 0
08-02 12:27:56.008   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 0 (VISIBLE)

============================== COLLAPSE ========================================

08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 0 (VISIBLE)
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginStart: 0
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginEnd: -156
08-02 12:27:51.015   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 8 (GONE)

=============================== EXPAND =========================================

08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 8 (GONE)
08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginStart: -156
08-02 12:27:56.007   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ marginEnd: 0
08-02 12:27:56.008   V/ExpandAnimation﹕ View is visible: 0 (VISIBLE)
```

As you can see the first `marginStart` of the expand is 0 but it has to be -156.

Comment: if its is related to the height computation of view  you can make it invisible instead of gone

Comment: Yes, and also the recycled views are working instantly.

Comment: could you please post your complete ListAdapter

Answer (score 2):

You did not show your XML but I assume you got `android:visibility="gone"` there. If so, you should remove it from layout file (so it is visible by default). if it should be gone, call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it after inflation. That way you will get the same result but view would also be able to get its dimensions.

Comment: I updated my post. I dont set visibility to gone in my layout file, i set it to gone in my listadapter.

Answer (score 2):

As your code stands, it reads the values for the margins as you have initialised them, as 0,0.

You'll need to set the view to `VISIBLE` to get margins, as set to `GONE` it will have zero margins.

So order your code like this:

```
this.viewToAnimate = view;

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

// Now the margins will not be zero.
this.marginStart = this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
this.marginEnd = (this.marginStart == 0 ? (0 - view.getHeight()) : 0);
```

Don't initialise these variables.

```
private int marginStart = 0;
private int marginEnd = 0;
```

or even this:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewToAnimateLayoutParams = null;
```

You only need to initialise the ones that need a start value for you algorithm.
Like bool values.

```
private boolean isVisibleAfter = false;
private boolean isEndedAlready = false;
```

I'm having issue with this line of code:

```
this.isVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
```

I don't understand why your code is not showing some warning or error in your logcat with this line.

`(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)` is not returning a value of visibility.

```
this.isVisibleAfter = view.getVisibility(); 
// will return the visibility of the view not a bool value.

if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
 // will  run only if the visibility is set to visible.
if(view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
if(view.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
```

It's not a boolean value. It can return one of three values.

I suggest changing it to:

```
if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

    this.isVisibleAfter = true;
}
else{
    this.isVisibleAfter = false;
}
```

Using `GONE` will just collapse the space taken up by that view. `INVISIBLE` will retain the space taken up by the view. Unless you want to keep your layout elements forced into a certain position, I would prefer `GONE`.

I hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. The same behaviour as before. And btw: `(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)` return true or false. `view.getVisibility()` and `View.VISIBLE` allone are returning int values. But if you say `(1 == 2)` you get false.